# in R, plot a nonlinear curve

Tags: r, plot, lines

There are several references that come close, but my lines() is producing multiple arcs instead of just one nonlinear curve.  It looks like a hammock with a bunch of unwanted lines.  How do you generate a simple nonlinear line?  Dataset available as Auto.csv at http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/data.html.

```
    library(ISLR)
    data(Auto)
    lm.fit1=lm(mpg~horsepower,data=Auto) #linear
    lm.fit2=lm(mpg~horsepower+I(horsepower^2),data=Auto) #add polynomial
    plot(Auto$horsepower,Auto$mpg,col=8,pch=1)
    abline(lm.fit1,col=2)       #linear fit
    lines(Auto$horsepower,predict(lm.fit2),col=4)  #attempt at nonlinear
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lines` plots the data in whatever order it happens to be in. As a result, if you don't sort by the x-value first, you'll get a mess of lines going back and forth as the x-value jumps back and forth from one row to the next. Try this, for example:

```
plot(c(1,3,2,0), c(1,9,4,0), type="l", lwd=7)
lines(0:3, c(0,1,4,9), col='red', lwd=4)
```

To get a nice curve, sort by `horsepower` first:

```
curve.dat = data.frame(x=Auto$horsepower, y=predict(lm.fit2))
curve.dat = curve.dat[order(curve.dat$x),]

lines(curve.dat, col=4)
```

[image]

Whereas, if you don't sort by `horsepower`, here's what you get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use `poly` for your polynomial fit. You can then use `curve` with `predict`:

```
lm.fit2 = lm(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2, raw = TRUE), data = Auto) #fit polynomial
#curve passes values to x, see help("curve")
curve(predict(lm.fit2, newdata = data.frame(horsepower = x)), add = TRUE, col = 4)
```

[image: resulting plot]

This also works with `nls` fits.

Comment: Thanks for the poly() suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way if you don't want to worry about sorting the dataframe first is to use `ggplot`. It has a useful method `geom_smooth` which lets you pick the formula and type of line you want to fit into your model:

```
library(ISLR)
library(ggplot2)
data(Auto)

ggplot(Auto, aes(mpg, horsepower)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y~x, se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y~x+I(x^2), se=FALSE, colour="red")
```

[image]